# How to retrieve a name of the frame in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to retrieve a name of the current frame using `elisp`. I have discovered that `name` is a part of frame's properties. The properties is an associated list. I do the following:

```
(cdr (assoc 'name (frame-parameters)))
```

But instead of the expected name I receive a mixed list of the name and some properties:

```
#("main-1" 0 5 (face nil) 5 6 (face nil))
```

How can I extract *"main-1"* from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are text properties on that string. You can use `substring-no-properties` to extract the plain string.

```
(substring-no-properties
 (cdr (assoc 'name (frame-parameters))))
```

Note that you may not need to do this. The propertized string *is* still a string, and `equal` to its no-properties version.

See also: <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Text Props and Strings` <kbd>RET</kbd>